# Why does function called inside a function return empty value?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, return

I have a function that gets initiated on page load. It is suppose to return a string item from an array/list. I have tested it and it seems to work fine:

```
function finder(file_list, evt_name) {
  file_list.forEach(function (item, index) {
      if (item.includes(evt_name)){
        console.log(item);
        return item;
      }
  });
}
```

I have a second function that is triggered by a button click event. Inside this function, I call my first function ('finder'):

```
document.getElementById("btnGetInterval").onclick = function () {
  ...
  var t_file = finder(tidal_files, event);
  var rv_file = finder(river_files, event);
  var rn_file = finder(rain_files, event);
...
}
```

In the console, when the `'finder'` function is called, it will `console.log(item)'` correctly and when it hits the break point it shows that the correct `item` will be returned, but when it returns inside the button click function, where I am trying to assign the returned value to a variable, it shows as `'undefined'`. Any reason why this would be happening? Any way to resolve it?

Comment: There is no `return` belonging to `finder` so.. The only `return` belongs to the anonymous function supplied to the forEach.

Comment: because you have to explicitly return something, otherwise functions returns undefined by default

Comment: `forEach` does not return anything (different than `undefined`).

Comment: Do not use `return` inside `forEach()`. It will not do what you are expecting, instead use a standard `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Return_value) always returns `undefined`, from the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Description):

> `forEach()` executes the `callback` function once for each array element; unlike `map()` or `reduce()` it always returns the value `undefined` and is not chainable. The typical use case is to execute side effects at the end of a chain.

You can use [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead and you must add `return` before `file_list.find(function (item, index) {`:

```
function finder(file_list, evt_name) {
    return file_list.find(function (item, index) {
        console.log(item);
        return item.includes(evt_name);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `find`.

```
function finder(file_list, evt_name) {
    return file_list.find(function (item, index) {
        return item.includes(evt_name);
    });
}
```